# With server side Blazor, how do I get a function to fire when a variable is changed?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I feel like this is a simple question but I cannot find the answer. I want a function to fire after a variable is changed in a server side Blazor application.

I am using a Mud Blazor MudMenu. This is an example of the code if it matters:

```
<MudMenu>
    <MudMenuItem @onclick="@(e => listValue= 1)">1</MudMenuItem>
    <MudMenuItem @onclick="@(e => listValue= 2)">2</MudMenuItem>
</MudMenu>
```

This is the variable in a @code block if it matters:

```
public int listValue;
```

My variable listValue does change when I select the appropriate item. I have a function that takes this value and makes an api call. How do I trigger that function when the variable changes?

Comment: More specific how? I know the value of the variable changes. What I don't know is how to fire a function after the change.

Comment: You calling a Lambda on click `(e => listValue= 1)` change that to a function call to set the listValue `((e) => SetListValue(1))`...

Comment: That's perfect thank you Brian

Comment: @Joe: Ah, you said `does change`, I misread that for `does not change`. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

You can do more things in the delegate you passed to OnClick:

```
MudMenuItem OnClick="ea => { listValue = 1; apiClient.DoSomething(listValue+1); }">...
```

Or declare a method that takes a MouseEventArgs:

```
MudMenuItem OnClick="DoThing">...

@code{
  void DoThing(MouseEventArgs ea){
    listValue = 1; 
    apiClient.DoSomething(listValue+1);
  }
}
```

Or declare a method with some other signature and giving a wrapping delegate that calls it:

```
MudMenuItem OnClick="_=>DoThing()">...

@code{
  void DoThing(){
    listValue = 1; 
    apiClient.DoSomething(listValue+1);
  }
}


MudMenuItem OnClick="_=>DoThing(listValue=1)">...

@code{
  void DoThing(int x){
   apiClient.DoSomething(x+1);
  }
}
```

<sup>That lattermost variation uses the fact that an assignment in C# returns the value that was assigned, which is then passed as the argument to the method- it's unusual, but legal.. I put it in more as a 'this is all just normal, legal C# method calling like any other syntax you can come up with</sup>

Or any other variation on the theme you can think of..